# How to change the color of one element not the whole elements?

Tags: button, flutter, specifications

I'm making five containers each of them contains IconButton with star icon in it, I want the star to switch colors when pressed on it, I used the variable `color2` which i initially put it equal to `Colors.grey` as it will be shown in the code. However, the problem is when i press on one of the icon buttons all the stars change their color. here's the code:

```
  class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  bool _star1;
  Color color1 =Colors.grey;
  Color color2=Colors.grey;
List<Meal> list1=[Meal(dis:'it is a chicken sandwichh',name: 'chekin filla',dat: '20th of september 2018'),
Meal(dis:'it is a chicken sandwichh',name: 'chekin filla',dat:'21th of september 2018'),
Meal(dis:'it is a chicken sandwichh',name: 'chekin filla',dat:'22th of september 2018'),
Meal(dis:'it is a chicken sandwichh',name: 'chekin filla',dat:'23th of september 2018'),
Meal(dis:'it is a chicken sandwichh',name: 'chekin filla',dat:'24th of september 2018')];

 change(){
   setState(() {
   if (color2==Colors.grey){
     color2=Colors.yellow;
   }
   else {
     color2=Colors.grey;
   }
   });
 }

 bool hi(String x){
  if (x!='22th of september 2018'&&x!='20th of september 2018'&&x!='21th of september 2018'){
   _star1 =true;
  }
  else{
    _star1=false;
  }
  return _star1;
}

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text('listviewww'),),
      body:
        ListView( children:list1
        .map((element){
          return Column(
            children: <Widget>[
          Container(
              child: Text(element.dat),),
          Container(
           margin: EdgeInsets.all(9.0),
           constraints: new BoxConstraints.expand(height: 300.0),
           decoration: new BoxDecoration(
           border: new Border.all(color: Colors.blueAccent),
           borderRadius: BorderRadius.horizontal( left:Radius.circular(30.0) ,right:Radius.circular(30.0) ),
           image: new DecorationImage(image: new AssetImage('assets/food1.jpg'),fit: BoxFit.cover,),),
           padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10.0),
      child:Column(
        children:<Widget>[ 
          Row(children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            padding:  EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 80.0),
            alignment: Alignment.topRight,
            child:IconButton(
              onPressed:(){ hi(element.dat)?null:change();},
              icon:Icon(Icons.star),color:color2 ,)),
            Expanded( 
              child: Column(  
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 1.0),
                  child: Text(
                    element.name,
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      fontSize: 40.0),),),
               Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 90.0),
                child:Text(element.dis,style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey[800],fontSize: 18.0),),),],), ),
               Container( 
                  padding:  EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 80.0),
                  alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                  child:IconButton(
                      onPressed:null,
                      icon:Icon(Icons.done_all,color: hi(element.dat)?Colors.grey:Colors.lightBlue,)),),],),],))],);  
        }).toList()));}}
```

**Edit**  I have added color as an element in the class as follows but if i pressed on any of the buttons the color does not change:

```
List<Meal> list1=[Meal(dis:'it is a chicken sandwichh',name: 'chekin filla',dat: '20th of september 2018',today:DateTime.now().subtract(Duration(days:2)),butcolor: Colors.grey),
Meal(dis:'it is a chicken sandwichh',name: 'chekin filla',dat:'21th of september 2018',today:DateTime.now().subtract(Duration(days:1)),butcolor: Colors.grey),
Meal(dis:'it is a chicken sandwichh',name: 'chekin filla',dat:'22th of september 2018',today:DateTime.now(),butcolor: Colors.grey),
Meal(dis:'it is a chicken sandwichh',name: 'chekin filla',dat:'23th of september 2018',today: DateTime.now().add(Duration(days:1)),butcolor: Colors.grey),
Meal(dis:'it is a chicken sandwichh',name: 'chekin filla',dat:'24th of september 2018',today: DateTime.now().add(Duration(days:2)),butcolor: Colors.grey)];

switchcolor(Color x ){
  setState(() {
if (x==Colors.yellow){
  x=Colors.grey;
}
else{
  x=Colors.yellow;
}
 });
}
child:IconButton(
              onPressed:(){ hi(element.today)?null:switchcolor(element.butcolor);},
              icon:Icon(Icons.star),color:element.butcolor,)),
```

Any idea?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is `hi(element.dat)` doing?..

Comment: Please add some more code.

Comment: it  returns true If the day doesnot come yet  else it returns false for passed days. As I want the upcoming days  to  be disabled as the user doesn't experience  it yet  so he cant judge if this is his favorite or not

Comment: @VirenVVarasadiya  have a look at the new edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here the problem is that you are using same variable for all list variable(color2) whenever anyone of stat is clicked then setState set second color which apply for all widget hence you are facing this issue. to avoid it you can add color attributes in list1's elements. and change that color on click event.

```
  import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

  void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

  class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return new MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        theme: new ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        ),
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        home: new MyHomePage(),
      );
    }
  }

  class Meal{
    String dis;
    String name;
    String dat;
    Color color = Colors.grey;

    Meal({String name, String dis,String dat,Color color}){
      this.dat = dat;
      this.name = name;
      this.dis = dis;
    }

  }

  class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
    @override
    _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
  }

  class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
    bool _star1;
    Color color1 =Colors.grey;
    Color color2=Colors.grey;
    List<Meal> list1=[
      Meal(dis:'it is a chicken sandwichh',name: 'chekin filla',dat: '20th of september 2018'),
      Meal(dis:'it is a chicken sandwichh',name: 'chekin filla',dat:'21th of september 2018'),
      Meal(dis:'it is a chicken sandwichh',name: 'chekin filla',dat:'22th of september 2018'),
      Meal(dis:'it is a chicken sandwichh',name: 'chekin filla',dat:'23th of september 2018'),
      Meal(dis:'it is a chicken sandwichh',name: 'chekin filla',dat:'24th of september 2018')
    ];

    change(Meal current){
      setState(() {
        if (current.color==Colors.grey){
          current.color=Colors.yellow;
        }
        else {
          current.color=Colors.grey;
        }
      });
    }

    bool hi(String x){
      if (x!='22th of september 2018'&&x!='20th of september 2018'&&x!='21th of september 2018'){
        _star1 =true;
      }
      else{
        _star1=false;
      }
      return _star1;
    }

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return new Scaffold(
          appBar: new AppBar(
            title: new Text('listviewww'),),
          body:
          ListView( children:list1
              .map((element){
            return Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  child: Text(element.dat),),
                Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.all(9.0),
                    constraints: new BoxConstraints.expand(height: 300.0),
                    decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                      border: new Border.all(color: Colors.blueAccent),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.horizontal( left:Radius.circular(30.0) ,right:Radius.circular(30.0) ),
                      ),
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10.0),
                    child:Column(
                      children:<Widget>[
                        Row(children: <Widget>[
                          Container(
                              padding:  EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 30.0),
                              alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                              child:IconButton(
                                onPressed:(){ hi(element.dat)?null:change(element);},
                                icon:Icon(Icons.star),color:element.color ,)),
                          Expanded(
                            child: Column(
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Container(
                                  alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 1.0),
                                  child: Text(
                                    element.name,
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                        fontSize: 40.0),),),
                                Container(
                                  margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 90.0),
                                  child:Text(element.dis,style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey[800],fontSize: 18.0),),),],), ),
                          Container(
                            padding:  EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 80.0),
                            alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                            child:IconButton(
                                onPressed:null,
                                icon:Icon(Icons.done_all,color: hi(element.dat)?Colors.grey:Colors.lightBlue,)),),],),],))],);
          }).toList()));}}
```

Comment: I have thought about this solution.However, thinking about having a huge number of icons is a horrible thing. Any suggestions to solve this ?

Comment: It did not work following the same concept; Could you please check my edit?

Comment: in this you just pass the color so it change the color but does not change in the object.

Comment: Yes!! this worked, thank you so much it was really appreciated. However i want to know why it did not work first although we changed the color in the property which is a part of the object;  I just want to understand the concept